# Cannot break specific Korean Characters

Tags: javascript, css, overflow, cjk, word-break

How can I break these characters?

> ᄀᄁᄂᄃᄄᄅᄆᄇᄈᄉᄊᄋᄌᄍᄎᄏᄐᄑ

As you can see, all of the characters are automatically moved to the new line to prevent overflowing but not the said Korean string above.

[image]

Already used these three, and nothing happened:

```
 word-wrap: break-word;
 white-space: pre-wrap;
 word-break: break-word;
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a horizontal scrollbar because the Korean text was unbreakable.